# Exchange EWS: How to retrieve original meeting information from MeetingResponse, if the original meeting is already deleted?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to retrieve original meeting information, provided I have the **MeetingResponse**
Normally I can get use of the **AssociatedCalendarItemId** in **MeetingResponse**, which is an **ItemId**, and then use **GetItem** to retrieve corresponding meeting information.

But, if the original meeting has already been deleted, you wont get **AssociatedCalendarItemId** in **MeetingResponse**. The field will be absent.

Use case:

1. user A sends meeting invitation to user B
2. user B accepts and sends response to user A
3. user A deletes the meeting
4. user A opens the response from user B

In step 4), I would expect to display the original meeting information while opening the response (which is what OWA and Outlook do). But since the **AssociatedCalendarItemId** is absent, I cant get the original meeting information. And in fact, the original meeting item doesnt exist any more.

I just want to have the same behavior as what OWA and Outlook do, to display meeting information while opening **MeetingResponse** (information including meeting time, chair, location, etc).

Anybody can help on this? Any comments will be appreciated. Many thanks to all.